# ¿Cómo saber si presionó una tecla sin ENTER en C++ con Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

mi problema esta en que no puedo saber que tecla presioné sin pulsar ENTER en **C++** con *Linux*. Conozco la función `GetAsyncKeyState()`, pero solo esta disponible en *Windows* con la biblioteca `<windows.h>`.

Las únicas soluciones que encontré fueron con `getch()` de `<conio.h>` pero es lo mismo, solo esta disponible en *Windows*.

***¿Qué librería o qué función debería utilizar para resolver esto?***

Es un programa en consola y estoy usando **C++14** con *Linux Mint 18.3*, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Aquí se muestra una versión de getch y de getche para gcc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035044/4743711

Comment: Mira si [esto](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets_unlocked) te sirve.

Comment: cin.get ()?  `if cin.get() == "d":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las librerías de C++, por defecto, no disponen de la funcionalidad que pides.

La razón hay que encontrarla en el funcionamiento que tiene el buffer de entrada del terminal. Hasta que no se pulsa *enter* no se le devuelve el control al programa, luego por los mecanismos tradicionales va a ser imposible.

No te puedo ofrecer una solución propia porque no dispongo de un sistema linux operativo ahora mismo sobre el que pueda permitirme el lujo de trastear. He recopilado un par de ejemplos que, a priori, podrían funcionar.

Una posibilidad, es usar el commando [stty](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ustty.htm) para modificar el comportamiento de la entrada. Este comando permite modificar el comportamiento de la entrada del terminal para que se adecue a tus necesidades ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799024/3819975)):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int c;
  /* configuramos el terminal para que las pulsaciones se envien
     directamente a stdin */
  system ("/bin/stty raw");
  while((c=getchar())!= '.') {
    /* Tienes que encontrar un mecanismo de escape alternativo a CTRL-D,
       ya que éste no funciona en el modo 'raw' */
    putchar(c);
  }
  /* Se restaura el modo normal de trabajo de la terminal */
  system ("/bin/stty cooked");
  return 0;
}
```

Otra posibilidad, un poco más engorrosa, pasa por desabilitar el flag 
*ICANON* (modo canónico) para permitir que el terminal te facilite los caracteres según los introduce el usuario. Este método debería estar disponible en los entornos UNIX ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798833/3819975)):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>    //termios, TCSANOW, ECHO, ICANON
#include <unistd.h>     //STDIN_FILENO


int main(void){   
    int c;   
    static struct termios oldt, newt;

    /* tcgetattr obtiene la configuración actual del terminal
       STDIN_FILENO se utiliza para escribir la configuración en oldt */
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    /* se hace una copia de la configuración */
    newt = oldt;

    /* se deshabilita el flag ICANON */
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);          

    /* se envia la nueva configuración a STDIN
       usamos TCSANOW para modificar la configuración. */
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    /* En este caso se usa la tecla 'e' para salir */
    while((c=getchar())!= 'e')      
        putchar(c);                 

    /* se restaura la configuración original */
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ;D